# Handling Forward Slashes ("//") In URL PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, api

I have a script that successfully parses data from a URL featuring JSON data.

However, when I add a new URL, that includes a colon (":") followed by two forward slashes ("//"), the code errors out. I feel it's due to how the script is interpreting ("://") in the URL.

I tried to replace ("://") with (":%2F%2F") in the URL parameter but, that did not work either.

Here's the script:

```
$cred = "[MY TOKEN]"
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $cred"; Accept = "application/json" }

$Output = Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Method Get `
  -Headers $headers `
  -ContentType: "application/json" `
  -Uri "https://www.example.com/id_user://234kjh-2234jh-45645l"
$result = $Output  | ConvertTo-Json
$result
```

The error is as follows:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"baseType":"error","code":"ServerError","message":"users.com 
\"234kjh-2234jh-45645l\" not found","status":500,"type":"error"}
At line:4 char:13
+ $Output = Invoke-RestMethod `
```

Comment: What if you escape the colon as well? `://` --> `%3A%2F%2F` (P.S. you're talking about backslashes, but in fact these are forward slashes)

Comment: didn't seem to work for me Theo. Have updated to "forward" slashes. Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure about that URL normally works from a browser? or something like Postman.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine and does, when I look it up, return JSON data. I have a very similar URL that does return JSON data when I run my script against it.

Comment: I confirmed that my powershell doesn't convert the `://` in the url to anything else, and they shouldn't have to be escaped (depending on the api...). If it works in a chromium browser, try to copy the web request as-powershell and see if something else is missing? https://www.powershellbros.com/powershell-tip-of-the-week-create-invoke-webrequest-from-chrome/

Comment: I have a feeling this is not due to powershell, but may be due to the api you are calling is returning an error, which then fails to convert using `ConvertTo-Json`. What do you get if you call `Invoke-RestMethod` directly and remove the last two lines?

Comment: To add to that. The reason I say it might be due to the API you are calling is because when I run your exact script as it is, but replace the URL with this `https://www.httpbin.org/anything/id_user://234kjh-2234jh-45645l` it works perfectly fine because httpbin is not returning an error.

Comment: turns out it was an issue with the token I was using. Had to create a new one and that work. Thanks all.